# Using hg commit --amend on dirty working copy to amend only the comment

Tags: mercurial

Modern Mercurial versions allow to `hg commit --amend` the prior commit.

Just now I wanted to to the same, but *exclusively* adjust the commit message of the previous commit, while my working copy had already been dirtied by additional edits. So I tried:

```
hg commit --amend --
```

which follows the GNU convention for arguments (`--` ends the option list and everything afterward are file/path names), in an attempt to pass an empty list of files.

However, as I learned, this still committed all the latest edits along with the commit comment change. It wasn't visible from the editor when I was prompted to edit my previous commit message, since I had been editing the same files that had been modified by the previous commit.

Is there a way to just amend the comment of the previous commit, without also committing file changes from the working copy?

(To clarify, I am in search of some concise command, I am aware that I could `shelve` my changes and then get them back from the shelf after amending the comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
hg commit --amend -e -X .
```

If you're using the evolve extension, there's also the shorter form:

```
hg amend -e -X .
```

The `-X .` option will exclude all files from being committed; the `-e` forces editing of the comment (otherwise you'll get a "nothing changed" error message).